# jquery if has class issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap tabs and I wanted to do some functions with javascript if `LI` is clicked but with conditional, if it's active do nothing, else do this...

I have come up with this code to check if it `has a class="active" since bootstrap tabs adds class="active" to LI for the active tab` but it doesn't work well, it always returns true, what I am doing wrong here?

code

```
var i = $( "li" ).hasClass( "active" );

$( "li" ).click(function() {            
    if (i == true ) {
        console.log("the tab is already active");
    }   
    else {
        console.log("selected");
    }      
});
```

here is **[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6udtbnuz/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check hasClass for clicked li:

```
$( "li" ).click(function() {            
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        console.log("the tab is already active");
    }   
    else {
        console.log("selected");
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(this)` for taken current object

```
$( "li" ).click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
       console.log("the tab is already active");
    }   
    else {
          console.log("selected");
    }

});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6udtbnuz/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Because $("li") returns all the li tags. And the initial state of the first li tab is active, so the i variable is always true.

Change the codes to what @Bhojendra Sah wrote will work.

Comment: oops am new to javascript didn't knew that. thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as well for dynamic elements:

```
$(document).on('click', "li.active", function (e) {

    console.log("the tab is already active");

}).on('click', "li:not(.active)", function (e) {

    console.log("selected");

});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6udtbnuz/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "li" ).click(function() {            
    if ($(this).hasClass("active") ) {
        console.log("the tab is already active");
    }   
    else {
        console.log("selected");
    }      
});
```